# Slow wifi in Lenovo Yoga Ideapad 13 when lid is closed

Tags: wireless, 20.04, lenovo

I have a dual boot (windows and Ubuntu 20.04) Lenovo laptop. I have had no issues with the WiFi until I started connected an external monitor. I initially thought it was something to do with the monitor, but then after testing different scenarios, I discovered that the WiFi is very slow when the lid is closed. I thought the best solution for this would be to get an Ethernet to USB adapter, as I sit right next to the WiFi router.

Unfortunately, even with the wired connection, there isn't a great improvement in the internet speeds. What could be the reason?

Here are the speeds for the different scenarios:

**Ubuntu 20.05**

Wireless with lid closed: 3.67 / 1.2 Mbps

Wireless with lid open: 20 / 13 Mbps

Wired with lid closed: 6.33 / 5.8 Mbps

Wired with lid open: 6.53 / 4.6 Mbps

**Windows 10**

Wireless with lid closed: 25 / 17 Mbps

Wireless with lid open: 28 / 22 Mbps

Wired with lid closed: 6.55 / 6.5 Mbps

Wired with lid open: 6.49 / 6.3 Mbps

The two speed values are from M-Lab's speed test and fast.com.

Just to show the actual speeds I get from the same broadband, this is the speed in my mobile phone:

**Mobile phone (connected to same WiFi): 64.3 / 46 Mbps**

Clearly the speeds in Ubuntu are much slower than Windows 10. What do I do? Thanks.